# how to catch and change the scheme of a url in react-native WebView?

Tags: ios, webview, react-native

I'm pointing the WebView to a site that uses both http and https. I would like to force the WebView to always connect to the https version of the pages. However whenever a link within the site is clicked it goes to http instead. Can this be accomplish with onNavigationStateChange?

The project requires that this is done in the app as the webview is pointing to a storefront. The storefront is on one of those do it yourself sites and the person I'm working with only has access to the cms of said site.

Comment: This is not a problem that should be addressed on the app level. The server hosting should be able to do the redirects by itself. There are several ways of accomplishing this depending on the web server being used.

Comment: I will update the question, however due to the nature of the project at this current time I have do it via the app if possible. I don't have direct access to the server as it's a storefront